# Error Code 0x80070022 when installing Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-installation

I encountered this error multiple times now:

- I downloaded the Media Creation Tool from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- I used the tool to download Windows 10 (happened to me with 1803, 1809 and 19H1)
- Plug it in the new PC and start the setup

The error occurs during the Windows installation. While it is extracting the files I get "Windows cannot install the required files. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070022". I tried different thumbdrives, redownloading Windows 10, changing USB ports (...) but nothing stops this error for me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I had a chat with the Microsoft Support and after explaining the problem they told me that this is a problem with the official Media Creation Tool. The support technician told me to download the ISO and burn it with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) and not with the MCT. I was pretty confused but it worked and he told me that this worked for others too.

Steps:

- Dowload Rufus and the MCT
- Download the ISO using the MCT
- Burn the ISO with Rufus

  - Partition Scheme: GPT
  - Target System: UEFI (non CSM)
  - File System: FAT32
  - Cluster Size: 16 kilobytes
  - Quick Format enabled
  - Create extended lable and icon files

> I couldn't find any proper documentation or even forum discussion where this was resolved so I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to reboot after the error. Then install again. This time do not remove partitions and just install it on the biggest partition which the previous setup created. It should fix the problem.